# Does JavaScript support Unicode ranges above 0xFFFF in regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

[This example regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/aM1fU5/11) (`^[\u0021-\u003F\u0041-\uFFEF]+@[\u0021-\u003F\u0041-\uFFEF]+\.[\u0021-\u003F\u0041-\uFFEF]+$`) can filter characters by their [Unicode character ranges](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/), and I can make ranges go from `\u0000` to `\uFFFF`, but Unicode supports characters beyond `0xFFFF`. Can I use ranges above these in JavaScript's regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For backwards compatibility with ECMAScript 5 and older environments, the unfortunate solution is to use surrogate pairs:

> ```
> >> '\uD83D\uDCA9'  
> '' // U+1F4A9 PILE OF POO
> ```
>
> In that case, each escape represents the code point of a surrogate half. Two surrogate halves form a single astral symbol.

Link: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Comment: With these surrogates, I don't suppose you could use surrogate ranges?

Comment: Isolated surrogate code points have no general interpretation; consequently, no character code charts or names lists are provided for this range Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters - CTRL+F -> "surrogates" - does that answer your question?

Comment: Seems this works (should support all characters, all surrogate pairs): `\u0000\u0000-\uFFFF\uFFFF` Example: https://regex101.com/r/aM1fU5/13

Comment: @Alexandru What will work to make a range is a combination of a hi- and a lo-surrogate range. E.g. `[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]` will act as if it was a single range matching *all* codepoints > 0xFFFF.  (Your solution only seemed to "work" because you weren't using it on any codepoints > 0xFFFF.)

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 2015 introduced the `RegExp` `u` flag to support Unicode escape sequences of higher values:

```js
(/\u{1F4A9}/u).test(""); // true
```

### References

- [MDN documentation for `RegExp.prototype.unicode`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode)
- [Specification of `RegExp.prototype.unicode`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-get-regexp.prototype.unicode)